# Tracking Website's Page Visitors and Statistic at IIS level

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

Is there any out of the box features available to Tracking Website's Page Visitors and Statistic at IIS level?

I am running an Asp.net website for an insurance company and the client needs to know the statistics of page visitors, how many of them are actually seeing policy amounts and how many of them are actually going to the final page and buying policies.

Answer (score 4):

By default, IIS logs site activity by using own log files. You can find log file configuration in IIS Manager where you can choose what fields, how often, and other settings.

Default path for log files is %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

If you need to create custom reports from time to time you could use [Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en), a command-line tool that provides a generic SQL-like language; and it allows you to export the result of the queries to many output formats such as CSV (Comma-Separated Values, etc), XML, SQL Server, Charts and others.

If you need reports on a regular basis you can try [IIS Log Analyzer](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2009/06/iis-log-analyzer) or search for other third party tool like [AWStats](http://www.awstats.org/).